# Проблема с версткой, как вставить блок в блоке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Вопрос к гуру верстки.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  height: 10%;
  background: #009e9d;
}

.content {
  background: #97969b;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.right-sidebar {
  background: #0010d5;
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  height: 60%;
}

.right-sidebar2 {
  background: #0110d5;
  float: both;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.footer {
  height: 10%;
  background: #009e9d;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">LOGO</div>
  <div class="right-sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="right-sidebar2">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="content">
    Какой-то текст, много текста, какой-то текст, много текста,<br> Какой-то текст, много текста, какой-то текст, много текста,<br> Какой-то текст, много текста, какой-то текст, много текста,<br>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Не получается вставить `right-sidebar2`. Он должен находится под `right-sidebar`.

Как можно исправить?

P.S. Убрать `right-sidebar2` совсем и использовать `div` внутри `right-sidebar` не предлагать. Мне нужны полноценные раздельные блоки с фиксированными неизменяемыми размерами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative; }

.header {
  height: 10%;
  background: #009e9d; }

.content {
  background: #97969b;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%; }

.right-sidebar {
  background: #0010d5;
  width: 20%;
  height: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;}

.right-sidebar2 {
  background: #0110d5;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;}

.clear {
  clear: both; }

.footer {
  height: 10%;
  background: #009e9d; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">LOGO</div>
  <div class="right-sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="right-sidebar2">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="content">
    Какой-то текст, много текста, какой-то текст, много текста,<br>     Какой-то текст, много текста, какой-то текст, много текста,<br>     Какой-то текст, много текста, какой-то текст, много текста,<br>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Попробуйте задать высоту контейнеру и спозиционируйте свои блоки через position:absolute, как вариант.

Answer (score 6):

В качестве варианта, предлагаю обернуть оба `sidebar` в один блок, который будет в себе содержать эти два блока, они будут раздельны.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  height: 10%;
  background: #009e9d;
}

.content {
  background: #97969b;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.right-sidebar {
  background: #0010d5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
}

.right-sidebar2 {
  background: #b7b8ce;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.footer {
  height: 10%;
  background: #009e9d;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">LOGO</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="right-sidebar2">Sidebar2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Какой-то текст, много текста, какой-то текст, много текста,<br> Какой-то текст, много текста, какой-то текст, много текста,<br> Какой-то текст, много текста, какой-то текст, много текста,<br>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Как вариант можно использовать `css-grid`, у него правда есть некоторые проблемы с поддержкой браузеров, так что тут надо быть осторожнее, но возможно этот вариант вам подойдет.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #d0d0d0
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: #ffb7b7cc
}

.right-sidebar {
  grid-area: right;
  background-color: #aac5ffcc
}

.right-sidebar2 {
  grid-area: right2;
  background-color: #bd0000
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #aeff79
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header header header header' 'content content content content content right' 'content content content content content right' 'content content content content content right2' 'footer footer footer footer footer footer';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper>div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="right-sidebar">right</div>
  <div class="right-sidebar2">right2</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: плюсик поставил) но я писал, что так не пойдет в примечание)

Comment: @hitcode У вас было описано немного по другому: "Убрать right-sidebar2 совсем и использовать div внутри right-sidebar не предлагать". А тут получается наоборот, не div внутри сайдбара, а сайдбары внутри div)

Comment: А понял, ну такой вариант тоже не хочется. Мне бы полноценные два блока. Это учебный пример.

Answer (score 1):

- К классу right-sidebar необходимо добавить - margin-left: 80%;
- К классу right-sidebar2 необходимо добавить - float: right;